# Command Gulp Serve with server configuration

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling, gulp

When I generate a spfx webpart/extension, i see this file generated (./config/serve.json) :

```
{
  "$schema": "https://dev.office.com/json-schemas/core-build/serve.schema.json",
  "port": 4321,
  "https": true,
  "serveConfigurations": {
    "default": {
      "pageUrl": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite/SitePages/myPage.aspx",
      "customActions": {
        "367a7af2-345d-4702-940c-61e4e4a103d2": {
          "location": "ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.CommandBar",
          "properties": {
            "sampleTextOne": "One item is selected in the list",
            "sampleTextTwo": "This command is always visible."
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "helloWorld": {
      "pageUrl": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite/SitePages/myPage.aspx",
      "customActions": {
        "367a7af2-345d-4702-940c-61e4e4a103d2": {
          "location": "ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.CommandBar",
          "properties": {
            "sampleTextOne": "One item is selected in the list",
            "sampleTextTwo": "This command is always visible."
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I figured that the "default" configuration is used when i typed `gulp serve`.
Is there any option to specify gulp serve command which configuration to use? Example :

```
gulp serve --configuration "helloWorld"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can specify which gulp command to run as below:

```
gulp serve --config=helloworld
```

Its a new section which has been added to the `serve.json` config file in SPFx projects.

So, when you run `gulp serve` the default entry will be used and when you specify `gulp serve --config=helloworld` that entry will used and you will be redirected according to the page specified in `pageUrl` value.

For more details, check out the below links :

Blogpost  - [Utilizing SPFx serveConfigurations](https://thechriskent.com/2017/11/03/utilizing-spfx-serveconfigurations/)

Youtube video - [Using serve.json to make SharePoint Framework Extension development easier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYLgb9LO23M&list=PLR9nK3mnD-OXZbEvTEPxzIOMGXj_aZKJG)